# Extending site to new template causes unrecognized style formats

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new developing both django and bootstrap. Is it possible to use both for templates?

I have a full html developed site with bootstrap that I want to use as base.html but when I extend it from another template it doesn't recognize any style format.

Is there a way to solve this problem? I have already installed django-bootstrap with pip.

My project has:

- Project
- Auth
- templates / inside : registration_folder / base.html
- static / inside : css / js / img
- manage.py

I am using django-registration thats why I have the registration_folder containing registration_form.html

In the registration_form.html I extend base.html and the form appears fine but the whole site has no style format. I have bootstrap files inside the corresponding folder from 'static'.

In base.html under head I have:

and setings.py : STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: Answer is YES - The question is too broad. You would get good responses if you are more specific in the questions you ask. Example, some piece of code that you are stuck with during the development, etc.

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't recognize any style format"

Comment: Also, django-bootstrap is only for Django form rendering, and is no longer maintained in any case. What are you trying to use it for?

Answer (score 1):

From experience: Yes. I've used Django as a framework and bootstrap as the frontend.

That being said, are you sure all of your links to the CSS and JS files are correct? same with the Django installation on the server? Because from experience, all I had to do was extend the base (assuming you know how extending works in django).

Comment: I have my {% extends "base.html" %} in the html file, and then, the base.html with all the code. Could it be an issue linking the stylesheets.
What I have is as if it were a regular static page like this: 
<link href="themes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Well maybe. I would use `<link href="themes/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>`, key thing is the slash at the end of the link, but I don't think it matters much. Do you have blocks in your base for the content you want to put in?

Comment: I have updated the post with more info, its missing the head line where I have <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding in the setings.py the path where the static files are located : STATICFILES_DIRS = '/Users/Name/Documents/Project/Site/static/' . I have read that doing that is not necesary, but it worked for me.
Do I  need to set that STATICFILES_DIRS when I upload the site?